# OpenIndiana Hipster boot problems

Tags: solaris, dual-boot, opensolaris, openindiana, illumos

I installed OpenIndiana Hipster on a separate GPT partition alongside other Unixes following this guide from [the openindiana wiki](https://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/Advanced+-+Manual+installation+of+OpenIndiana+from+LiveCD+media). After I finished, I tried to boot into the fresh installation but it stops at loading `tzmon` (as reported by verbose boot). The live media boots just fine, however. This is unfortunately all the debugging info I could gather, as the system doesn't finish the boot process. Please help me!

Comment: It's going to be long, but can you capture and post the verbose boot output from both a successful live media boot and one from your disk that hangs?  If you can't do that, boot the live media in verbose mode and post what happens immediately *after* loading `tzmon`.  Assuming the live media and the normal boot sequence is the same, that's probably what's hanging in your normal boot process.

Comment: I filmed the boot process and uploaded the videos to youtube: [local HDD](https://youtu.be/hYwOWeXl1Bc) and [live media](https://youtu.be/2VvV4MpoUqk). Should I also upload the dmesg output of the live medium boot?

Comment: Yes, the `dmesg` output might be helpful. I had a Dell years ago that was similar. It would boot if I disabled hyperthreading and all but one CU in the BIOS. The fix was an ACPI or APIC boot setting, unfortunately I don't recall the exact setting.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2379/ghckl/index.html for how to modify kernel boot options via the GRUB menu. You can try disabling hyperthreading and/or all but one CPU in the BIOS, or you can try booting with something like `-B acpi-user_options=0x2`

Comment: Here is the [dmesg output](https://pastebin.com/cm5eJPzk)

Comment: OK, after `tzmon` is loaded, the live media boot then loads the USB drivers.  Assuming the boot order for the HDD boot is the same, that seems to indicate that the HDD boot is hanging while loading the USB drivers. Check the live boot GRUB menu to see what parameters are being passed to the kernel, and if there are any, try adding them to the HDD boot GRUB menu.  If there aren't any, you can try modifying the USB BIOS settings.

Comment: Since you note being able to boot off the live media, have you tired to import/mount your installed image?  If so, you may find something hidden in a log file.

Comment: @Andrew Henle the newer OI version don't use grub by default, but the boot loader ported from FreeBSD. This loader is sadly not really all that well documented yet, but as far as I can gather it has less options than grub.

Comment: @sleepyweasel I tried that, but I couldn't find any (non-empty) log files. Probably the boot process doesn't progress far enough for the system logger daemon to start.

Comment: @spacelander *the newer OI version don't use grub by default* I was not aware of that change. What USB options does your BIOS have?

Comment: Just USB legacy on or off.

Answer (score 2):

It seams to be a problem with the OI image. I installed OmniOS and it boots up perfectly.